# How to change api provider in wso2 api manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 apim 4.0.0. Some dozen of apis are deployed and published on it by admin user. Consequently the provider of those apis is admin(in wso2 db). The question that I would like to ask is if it possible to change api provider to another user. If it is then how to do that?
I tried to change it directly in wso2am_db (wso2 api manager database), but haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API Provider will always be the user who creates the API. Directly updating the tables may result in data inconsistency. If you want to show it  as owned by a different user in **Developer Portal**, you can add that user as `Business Owner` of the API, under `Business Info`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible. Provider is user who created api. You can log in like admin, delete your api. Log in(in publisher or restfull api) like a different user and then create/deploy your api.